# Remove string and everything after for each element containing certain string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, wordpress, menu

I have an online store with menu items which need a certain part of their name cut off as its only for my reference.

The part of the string I want to cut is "-123-" and everything after.
e.g. "fender-123-guitar" would become "fender"

There are multiple instances of menu items with "-123-" in it so I need to do it for all automatically (not one by one.)

The strings can be selected like so:
    $( 'li.menu-item > a' ).text()

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to be "one by one", but that's how it should be done ?

```
$( 'li.menu-item > a' ).text(function(_,txt) {
    return txt.split('-123-').shift();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/djvtde9t/)

Comment: Will it loop automatically until there are no more "-123-"s left?
That's what I mean by automatic (sorry for vagueness)

Comment: Hey! you did it!
I love you <3
Thank you for your help!